# Export to Excel - IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-8, export-to-excel

The following export code works in IE7 and FF, but not IE8. What needs to change for this to work in IE8?

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            this.WriteFile(HtmlTable);
        }

        void WriteFile(string content)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + _fileName + "\"");
            context.Response.Charset = "";
            //context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            context.Response.Write(content);
            context.Response.End();
        }
```

This is how we call it from the front end:

```
function resultsGridExportToExcel()
        {
            var exportUrl = '/extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/SavedIndicationsExportToExcel?id=3'; 
            var postData = jQuery('#resultsGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'); 
            $.each(postData, function(key, value) 
            { 
                exportUrl += '&'+key+'='+encodeURIComponent(value); 
            }); 
            $('#SaveIndicationsExportForm').attr('action', exportUrl).submit(); 
        }
```

And here is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SavedIndicationsExportToExcel(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            SavedIndication indication = new SavedIndication();

            var jqGridData = indication.GetSavedIndications(sidx, sord, 1, Int32.MaxValue);
            var gridDefinition = SavedIndication.GridDefinition;

            string filename = "Indications Calculator - Saved Indications";

            string htmlTable = jqGridData.RenderHtmlTable(gridDefinition.RetrieveColumnHeaders());
            htmlTable = Chatham.Web.Controllers.ExcelResult<string>.RemoveImages(htmlTable);
            return new ExcelResult() { FileName = filename, HtmlTable = htmlTable };
        }
```

It debugs all the way through, no errors, runs fine, but doesn't generate any output in IE8, only in IE7 and FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with IETester.

It doesn't like popups and a screen had to popup for the download. On a REAL IE machine, this worked.